# Hovering over li element not showing div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello I am new to HTML and CSS, and I was trying to display the contents of a div element when I hover over a li element. So basically what I am trying to do is when I hover over one li element (say: ls1), I want to display dv2. However, my code does not display the contents even when I hover over it. Please help!! Thank you.**

```js
const list_dv1 = document.querySelectorAll('.dv1 li');

function show_item() {
  list_dv1.forEach((item) =>
    item.classList.remove('hovered'));
  this.classList.add('hovered');

}

list_dv1.forEach((item) =>
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', show_item));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.dv1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dv1 li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  margin: 20px;
}

.dv2 {
  background-color: greenyellow;
  color: black;
}

.dv2 {
  display: none;
}

.ls1:hover+.dv2 {
  display: block;
}

.dv3 {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <title>Practice Hiding Elements</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="dv1">
      <ul>
        <li class="ls1">Hover over me once</li>
        <li class="ls2">Hover over me twice</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dv2">You found me!</div>
    <div class="dv3">You found me twice!</div>

  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: With your CSS implementation `.ls1:hover + .dv2` won't work as `.dv2` is not next to / the next element on the page. The `+` selector only targets the next element.

Comment: With your JS solution, you target the list elements, however you never change the div's. Can you write a query selector for the div?

Comment: Oh. Okay. Thank you. I will try to add the action for the div's

Comment: You are adding a class called hovered in the JS, but this isn't in the CSS - and you want to pick up a different div to the one the user is hovering over. The pseudo class :hover in CSS won't help you in this case for the reasons given in other comments.